# Issue : Application deployment on glassfish 7

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

This is the error I am facing shown in glassfish server logs. I have tried adding JSTL jakarta dependencies but issue not resolved. Majority of dependencies are already on jakarta.

```
[GF 7.0.8] [SEVERE] [] [jakarta.enterprise.web.vs.server] [tid: _ThreadID=52 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  WebModule[/cp]Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldListener
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.HttpContextLifecycle.contextDestroyed(jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)" because "this.lifecycle" is null
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldInitialListener.contextDestroyed(WeldInitialListener.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStop(StandardContext.java:3980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4670)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4469)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:935)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:644)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1795)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1483)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:596)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:587)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1478)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:425)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
]]

[2023-10-17T14:03:42.221887Z] [GF 7.0.8] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00108] [jakarta.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=52 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error invoking ServletContainerInitializer org.glassfish.wasp.runtime.TldScanner
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:935)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:644)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1795)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1483)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:596)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:587)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1478)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:425)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error invoking ServletContainerInitializer org.glassfish.wasp.runtime.TldScanner
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:4544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4447)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/SimpleTagSupport
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:588)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:922)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:840)
    at org.glassfish.wasp.runtime.TldScanner.addListenerAndCreateTags(TldScanner.java:656)
    at org.glassfish.wasp.runtime.TldScanner.scanJar(TldScanner.java:580)
    at org.glassfish.wasp.runtime.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.wasp.runtime.TldScanner.scanTlds(TldScanner.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.wasp.runtime.TldScanner.onStartup(TldScanner.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:4539)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:942)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:840)
    ... 61 more
]]

[2023-10-17T14:03:42.223885Z] [GF 7.0.8] [WARNING] [] [jakarta.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=52 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [levelValue: 900] [[
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error invoking ServletContainerInitializer org.glassfish.wasp.runtime.TldScanner
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error invoking ServletContainerInitializer org.glassfish.wasp.runtime.TldScanner
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:644)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1795)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1483)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:596)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:587)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1478)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:425)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
]]
```

JDK 17
Glassfish 7

Dependecies inside pom.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.3.jre17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <!-- Gson for Object conversion to json                                         * -->
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core-jakarta -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <!-- Swagger jar files                                         * -->
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <!-- Swagger jar files                                         * -->
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <!-- Swagger jar files                                         * -->
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <!-- Swagger jar files                                         * -->
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <!-- Antisamy used to data validation                                         * -->
        <!-- ********************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.antisamy</groupId>
            <artifactId>antisamy</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ozlerhakan</groupId>
            <artifactId>poiji</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>${dozer.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--For FlyWay Jar-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct-processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.forwardyou.fwtech.integrations</groupId>
            <artifactId>sei-client</artifactId>
            <version>${sei.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.forwardyou.fwtech.integrations</groupId>
            <artifactId>generic-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>${sei.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.forwardyou.fwtech.integrations</groupId>
            <artifactId>docuware</artifactId>
            <version>${sei.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run an older application with GlassFish 7, which requires that your application uses jakarta prefix and not javax prefix.

According to the error about the `org.glassfish.wasp.runtime.TldScanner`, it looks like some your application contains a tag library, with a tag that references the "javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport" class in the `tag-class` element.

Search for the "javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport" string in your application and replace it with "jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport" if you find it. It might also be used inside a dependency JAR file. However, it doesn't look like ay of your dependencies would bring a tag library to your application.

There's also a `NullPointerException` from the `WeldInitialListener` but I think that happens because your application fails to deploy because of the SimpleTagSupport error.

If you need any professional help with upgrading to GlassFish 7, [OmniFish](https://omnifish.ee/) provides commercial support for GlassFish.